# How to pass variable to filter condition dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have files (10.230.30.146_480.txt, 10.20.24.16_480.txt, 10.55.30.2_383.txt), I need to use the first part of the file name as variable1 and the second part as variable2

I used the code to do that

for txt in na_sheets:

x=txt.replace('.txt','')

y= x.split("_", 1)

variable1 = y[0]

variable2=y[1]

df1=df[(df['MSAN_IP'] == 'variable1') & (df['OUTER_VLAN'] == variable2)]

Then I made for loop to iterate the variables variable1 and variable2
and filter dataframe df and pass this variables to the filer condition

The output is Empty DataFrame has the headers only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
na_sheets = [
    "10.230.30.146_480.txt",
    "10.20.24.16_480.txt",
    "10.55.30.2_383.txt"
]

dfs = {
    fn: df.loc[(df["MSAN_IP"] == v1) & (df["OUTER_VLAN"] == int(v2))] 
    for fn in na_sheets for v1, v2 in [fn.rstrip(".txt").split("_")] # maxsplit=1 ?
}
```

*NB: This will make a dictionnary of DataFrames where the keys are the filenames.*

Output :

```
for k, v in dfs.items():
    print(k, v, sep="\n", end="\n\n")

10.230.30.146_480.txt
         MSAN_IP  OUTER_VLAN
2  10.230.30.146         480

10.20.24.16_480.txt
       MSAN_IP  OUTER_VLAN
0  10.20.24.16         480

10.55.30.2_383.txt
      MSAN_IP  OUTER_VLAN
1  10.55.30.2         383
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "MSAN_IP": ["10.20.24.16", "10.55.30.2", "10.230.30.146"],
    "OUTER_VLAN": [480, 383, 480],
})
```

Comment: **NB:** To retrieve a specific *DataFrame*, you can use *dictionnary key-indexing*: `dfs[filename]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the result because your for loop is overriding values and you are getting only the last value. You can do:

```
na_sheets = (
    "10.230.30.146_480.txt",
    "10.20.24.16_480.txt",
    "10.55.30.2_383.txt"
)

k=[txt.replace('.txt','').split("_", 1) for txt in na_sheets]
#[['10.230.30.146', '480'], ['10.20.24.16', '480'], ['10.55.30.2', '383']]

variable1 = [x[0] for x in k]
#['10.230.30.146', '10.20.24.16', '10.55.30.2']

variable2 = [x[1] for x in k]
#['480', '480', '383']
```

Now you can use them in a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "MSAN_IP": variable1,
    "OUTER_VLAN": variable2,
})
```